# How to display INR wth perl?

Tags: perl

How to create a Indian rupee symbol with perl code and print it on screen or file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a **one-liner perl**:
`perl -e 'binmode(STDOUT, ":utf8");print "\x{20B9}\n"'`

**Output:**
`₹`

**Explanation:**
1) `binmode(STDOUT, ":utf8");`
Sets the out standard output from perl to support UTF8. This UTF8 allows you to display extended symbols

2) Unicode value for Rupee is `U+20B9` (Refer [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_rupee_sign))

3) To display this 
`print "\x{20B9}\n"`
Pushes this symbol to standard Output. And above setting (1) configured Standard Output to support it's output, which is **₹**

You may embed this snippet in your code.
I hope it helps others too! :)

Comment: I am not getting the output for perl version of 2006

Comment: oh ok.. for me, `perl -version`

This is **perl 5, version 14, subversion 2 (v5.14.2)** built for `x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi`
(with 55 registered patches, see perl -V for more detail)..

Will see if i can find something for your version of perl.. will suggest though to upgrade your version, if legacy code is not an issue! :)

Comment: Thanks so much for your concern Vishal

Comment: i am using perl v5.8.8 built for msys-64int - 1987-2006

Comment: @user1613245: Works fine for me, `This is perl, v5.8.4 built for i386-linux-thread-multi`

Comment: It would be better to `use charnames qw(:full)` so that you can use `\N{INDIAN RUPEE SIGN}` or `\N{RUPEE SIGN}` or whatever you need. Otherwise you put Evil Magic Numbers of Exceeding Mystery in your code.